# Click selector in angular template and navigate to typescript/html

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Is there an extension for VSCODE that lets you click the selector in a template and clicking it would open the component. I know that clicking the attribute of a selector can bring you to the typescript code but is it possible if you have no attributes?

Comment: [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) does that. Remember that for full support of it's features you need to have [`strictTemplates`](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-mode) enabled.